# RDP Acceleration

Tags: hyper-v, windows-terminal-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Faster RDP](https://serverfault.com/questions/217763/how-to-get-faster-rdp)

HI

Does anyone have experience of any good RDP Acceleration software / hardware.

We are running over 250 terminal server connections to hyper-v servers and when our users access Flash or PDFs the lag is really bad.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is msiexec.exe getting kicked off when they open a PDF?
Slow performance even for a plain text based PDF that has no multimedia?
What OS?
Disable javascript in any PDF reader as javascript makes it so much more vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in fact this question was answered in another post, so instead of needlessly copying information, I'll link you to it: [How to get Faster RDP](https://serverfault.com/questions/217763/how-to-get-faster-rdp/217773#217773)

Answer (score 0):

I'm very happy with [Ericom Blaze for RDP acceleration](http://www.ericom.com/ericom_blaze.asp). It works on Mac, Windows, Linux and has packages for the common thin client devices.

As a consultant, I  use it to get to my co-located systems with minimal lag. I've also deployed it in scenarios where terminal services users need video or to interact with rich content (Flash websites, Google Maps, etc.). The test for me was being able to run a Youtube video over a T1 with 75ms roundtrip latency without dropping any audio, video frame or any screen-painting.